# Identifying Infinity, Indeterminate, etc

Tags: pattern-matching

I am doing a calculation and sometimes in the middle of the calculation a parameter evaluates to the following

```
ft = 3/2 (Interval[{-∞, ∞}] - 
 0.182269836621496581329460089919307050446571501722246222934`32. \
 (Interval[{Indeterminate, Indeterminate}] + 
    Interval[{-∞, ∞}]) - 
 0.0509521859494036386356673163441370150570327833689743828576`32. \
  (Interval[{Indeterminate, Indeterminate}] + 
    Interval[{-∞, ∞}]));
```

I am trying to identify the "Infinity" "Interval" "Indeterminate" so I can stop the calculation and warn the user.  I do the following

```
Print[MemberQ[N[uSolz],ComplexInfinity]];
Print[MemberQ[N[uSolz],Infinity]];
Print[MemberQ[N[uSolz],Indeterminate]];
Print[MemberQ[N[uSolz],Indeterminate]];
```

or

```
Print[StringMemberQ[ToString[uSolz],"Indeterminate"]]
```

or I evaluated my function in some points because normally uSolz has r as a variable.

```
rrange=N[Range[0,2,(0-2)/1000]];
Print[N[uSolz/.r->rrange]];
```

From above I was hoping to get some infinity etc.

None of them worked for me. 
Any ideas?

Comment: maybe `Not@FreeQ[#, DirectedInfinity[_] | Indeterminate, {0, Infinity}] &@N[uSolz]`?

Comment: I'd replace `DirectedInfinity[_]` with `_DirectedInfinity` in @kglr's pattern, so that `ComplexInfinity` is caught as well.

Comment: @J.M. good point. `DirectedInfinity[___]` works as well but is longer.

Comment: @kglr @ J.M It looks like it is working :) , thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f = Not[FreeQ[#, _DirectedInfinity | Indeterminate, {0, ∞}]]&
f @ ft
```

> True

Answer (score 1):

Note that [`Infinity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infinity), [`Indeterminate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indeterminate) etc. are not numbers:

```
NumberQ[Infinity]
NumberQ[Indeterminate]
NumberQ[ComplexInfinity]
```

> False
>
> False
>
> False

So, you can define a predicate to identify [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval) objects with a non-number element:

```
badIntervalQ[Interval[a__]] := AnyTrue[Flatten @ a, Not@*NumberQ]
```

Check:

```
FreeQ[ft, _Interval?badIntervalQ]
```

> False

meaning that `ft` contains a bad interval.